# Uploading to S3 using Python Requests

Tags: python, amazon-s3, python-requests

I'd like to upload xml's directly to S3 without the use of modules like boto, boto3, or tinys3.

So far I have written:

```
 url = "https://my-test-s3.s3.amazonaws.com"
 with open(xml_file,'rb') as data:
     requests.put(url, data=data)
```

and I've gone and head and set the AllowedOrigin on my S3 bucket to accept my server's address.

This does not error when running, however, it also does not seem to be uploading anything.

Any help would be appreciated --- I'd like to (a) get the thing to upload and (b) figure out how to apply AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretAccessKey to the request

Comment: See the official docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html They clarify the exact content of the request.

Comment: @mjabraham would you like to use any other modules apart from the above mentioned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to upload xml's directly to S3 without the use of modules like boto, boto3, or tinys3 I would recommend to use `awscli`:

```
pip install awscli
aws configure  # enter your AWSAccessKey and AWSSecretAccessKey credentials
```

`AWSAccessKey` and `AWSSecretAccessKey` will be stored inside `~/.aws` folder permanently after using `aws configure`.

And then you can upload files using python:

```
os.system("aws s3 cp {0} s3://your_bucket_name/{1}".format(file_path, file_name))
```

Docs are [here](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/).

Answer (score 1):

you need to install `awscli` following this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/installing.html).
Then in a commandline shell, execute `aws configure` and follow the instruction.

to upload file, its much easier using `boto`

```
import boto3
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
s3.meta.client.upload_file(xml_file, 'yourbucket', 'yours3filepath')
```

Alternatively, you can use `aws s3 cp` command combined with python `subprocess`.

```
subprocess.call(["aws", "s3", "cp", xml_file, "yours3destination"])
```